# Passing "|" as an argument to unix script

Tags: csv, unix, pipe, parameter-passing, delimiter

I have written a generic unix script to load oracle table from any csv.Now the delimeter(field seperator) in the csv can be anything like ',' or '|" or ':' etc.
Hence i am trying to pass the delimeter as an argument to the script explicitly and its working fine for most of the delimeters but when i am trying to pass | then its not giving me proper result as it is implicitly converting | to ,

```
ksh -x myscript csv_name |
```

# not working

```
ksh -x myscript csv_name ,
```

# working

Please suggest me if there is in escape used for this?

Comment: What about the usual suspects? `\|` or `"|"`?

Comment: Try also `ksh -x myscript csv_name '\|'` - it is possible that the script is trying to use the delimiter in a regular expression and trips on the `|` character, which has special meaning in regexps.

Comment: It's difficult to answer without seeing "myscript".  Once the "pipe" character gets into the shell script, almost anything can go wrong.

One thing to consider is translating the "pipe" to something else and using that in your script.  The reason I suggest this is that the shell is going to fight you every step of the way.  Even if you translate it to a ctrl-a, or something, it would probably be easier than trying to escape every regex and every variable expansion, while leaving legitimate "pipe"s alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested in my machine, you need to use below command -

```
ksh -x test.sh file "|"
```

OR

```
ksh -x test.sh file \|
```

OR

```
ksh -x test.sh file '|'
```

We need to disable the functionality of "|" using escape,single or double quotes.

> Testing -

```
cat file
A|B|B|A
A|A|A
B|A|B|A
B|B
A|A
A|B
A|A|B

cat test.sh
vFile=$1
sep=$2
awk -F "$sep" '{print $1,$2}' ${vFile}

ksh -x test.sh file "|"
A B
A A
B A
B B
A A
A B
A A
```